# C# WebClient.DownloadFile issue with UrlEncoding

Tags: c#, webclient

I have an url like this https://example.com/4654ds-dsds5-982/file%20%281%29.pdf?token=xxxxxxxx

I use WebClient.DownloadFile to download this file but the URL changed to https://example.com/4654ds-dsds5-982/file%20(1).pdf?token=xxxxxxxx when String is converted to Uri

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient()) {
    wc.DownloadFile(new Uri(myURL), myPATH);
}
```

My problem is the token to download file is sync with the file name give by the API we use so the URL must be exactly the same (with the same encoded characters)

Any suggestion to download a file from URL without my input URL changed ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the old HttpWebRequest class

```
var url = " https://example.com/4654ds-dsds5-982/file%20%281%29.pdf?token=xxxxxxxx";
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
    var destination = "<some local folder>";
    var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    using (var fileStream = File.Create(destination))
    {
        responseStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
    }
}
```

Comment: Same problem. If you print the result of request.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri you can see the Uri is changed.
You can see the HttpWebRequest.Create(string uri) method convert string to Uri [Microsoft source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system/net/System/Net/WebRequest.cs,6216de40b052b741,references)